# Access children class type in super static method

Tags: java, android, inheritance

I have two class A and B like this :

```
class A{
    //Must return children type
    static Class myStaticMethod(){
         return ????????????????
    }
}

class B extends A{
}
```

I have this command :

```
B.myStaticMethod() //Must return B
```

I don't want to make any code in class B but just get the children type in super static method.

I don't know if it's possible.

EDIT :

this is why i want to do this :

I have an abstract activity :

```
abstract public class CPAppCompatActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public static void start(Context pContext) {
        Class subclass = ??????
        pContext.startActivity(new Intent(pContext, subclass));
    }
}
```

and an activity :

```
public class SignUpActivity extends CPAppCompatActivity {

}
```

I want to launch my activity like this :

```
SignUpActivity.start(this.getApplicationContext())
```

Comment: It is not. A does and should absolutely **not** know about its subclasses; so the idea that a static method in A knows something about Bs is a really bad idea OO design wise. So, lets step: what kind of problem do you intend to solve here?

Comment: You *could* use *reflection* to solve this, but, might I ask, why do you want  to do this?

Comment: @Bathsheba How would you do that? Reflection can't tell you about child classes, you would have to iterate like all classes that your JVM knows about to find those that extend A. As said: this smells like the very wrong answer to a problem he didn't tell us about.

Comment: See the why in my edit, many thanks for your times

Comment: @GhostCat: That's *exactly* how you'd do it. But you *can* descriminate by "jar" so at least you don't necessarily have to traverse every class. But really, this is an X-Y problem.

Comment: Hmmm, maybe it's feasable with a Typeparamter? `static T myStaticMethod()` in parent and parent class with T param and when extending : `class ChildClass extends ParentClass<ChildClass>` ... perhaps or at least similar?